# Need help on bar button item in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, toolbar, uitoolbar

I have the weirdest issue today. I always use toolbar and bar button item button and never have problem. Here is the issue:
I have view and the bottom has toolbar. In the toolbar, I create two bar button items which are 'back' button and 'next' button. For some reason, when i build into simulator or iphone, those buttons are not sensitive like before. On other words, the buttons do not really work. I found out that the half part (top) of the buttons are working when you touch it or use mouse cursor to click it. But the other half (down) of the buttons are not working at all.
Anybody has this kind of issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have some other view in the way of the bottom half of the toolbar.  Any chance you meant to put one off screen but calculated wrong?

Comment: post the code how you created the toolbar and bar button items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half of the toolbar means status bar's height. Double check your view's height and change according to your status bar.

Comment: It is so weird. I even delete all the objects and recreate a new view.
The view is 320x460. The toolbar is 320x44, with Y is 416 and X is 0.
If I drag a toolbar little bit above, so I can see a white space just like for iAd and the bar buttons are fully working.

Comment: You have AdBannerView as well? Can you post a screenshot of what you have from interface builder and any code relevant to the subject?

Comment: I am ok now. For some reason, it is working today after I create all the view, nav bar, toolbar and etc. I think the status bar might be the issue, maybe...but you brought up the good point. Thanks anyway.