# Toolbar bar button item not working properly in SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having a weird problem that is similar to [this post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/322034-strange-problem-with-uibutton-in-bar-button-item.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159486/need-help-on-bar-button-item-in-xcode). My toolbar's far left bar button item's touch censor is off place. In my case this only happens when I add toolbar in DetailViewController in SplitViewController and run it on the iPhone.

Red field is the off place touch censor for the item button.

[image: Red field is the off place touch censor for the item button.]

I've tried many things and those are the things that I found out. I'm using Xcode 6.

- It only happens when toolbar is in DetailViewController of SVC
- It only happens when you run it on iPhone and not iPad
- It only happens when it's constrained to the bottom of the DetailViewController
- It only happens to the button on the far left of the toolbar

Has anyone had the same problem before? If not, I would very much appreciate it if you could try it yourself by simply creating a new Master-Detail project and add toolbar in DetailViewController and constrain it to the bottom and run it on the iPhone simulator or a device. Please share if it causes a same problem. There doesn't seem to be any clear answer to this so I'm wondering if there's a issue with the Xcode. Only solution I came up with is to use tab bar instead. Please share your thoughts or solution on this.

**Edit:**

I've connected the Item button to IBAction and it does get triggered when I touch on Item. I thought it was not working because it doesn't give the flash animation unless I touch the red field. IBAction gets called but it still doesn't give the flash animation unless I touch on the red field. And touch censor field for the item button seems too large.

Comment: I was able to confirm your issue. What I found, however, is that the action is triggered even though the button push isn't animated. The action is also triggered if you hit the area to the right of the button (as you noted in the color red above). I want to confirm: did you try adding an action to the button and seeing if it's triggered by clicking it (despite the lack of animation)?

Comment: @J Shapiro Thanks for your reply. I had just given up on this issue and moved on with my project and added the action to the button, and it worked! Thanks for confirming the issue. It was driving me nuts. Still there is no flash animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also found out that I cannot change the title of this button in code with method like `self.itemButton.title = @"Changed Title";`, but I solved this by switching between two buttons.

```
- (IBAction)editAction:(id)sender {
    [self.toolBar setItems:@[self.doneButton]];
}

- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
    [self.toolBar setItems:@[self.editButton]];
}
```

**Update:**

This issue has been resolved in Xcode 6.2.