# Button does not react

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsbutton

I have a strange behaviour with an `NSButton`. It works normal until I do so voodoo somewhere else in my app. Right then the button does no longer react on click events. It still looks normal (so not disabled). It just does not do anything when I click it. Any idea where I should look in the properties of `NSButton` that might have been changed accidentally? (Quite sure I did not touch the button itself.)

Comment: Ensure the button is enabled

Comment: @ChoppinBroccoli As said, it looks enabled (not grayed out).

Comment: What is the `voodoo` that you mention, can you show the code that breaks the button?

Comment: @Wezly Unfortunately that is not possible. It's a large app and it's not a single place where that happens. But always to that single button. Is there anything that could explain this strange behavior. Never seen it this way.

Comment: I'm guessing the button is either being "hidden" behind a transparent image or being disabled indirectly due to one of the objects containing it.  I've in a couple of cases found it necessary to write a recursive descent routine to find what image was "hiding" a button in this fashion.

Comment: @HotLicks Rather unlikely, but I'll check what the superview will offer in its subviews.

Comment: I even verified recursively from the contentview that nothing got in the way

Comment: @Thomas Kilian Do you mean your button is not giving the flash animation? Or it does't trigger the action?

Comment: @sansof It does not flash. Checked action/target: both ok. Nothing in the way. I also moved the button to somewhere else and re-created it. Pullng my hairs :-( Got to go to bed now.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your button is in a 'touchable' zone in its superView. I mean It have ro be placed inside it superView bounds (If not, you can see It, depending on Clipping properties, and you can't interact with It). In order to check it, set a color to your container view.
Also check userInteraction is enabled...

Hope It helps.

Comment: The button is aside others that work properly. What do you mean by `userInteraction`? That's not a property of `NSButton`

Comment: @Bisca may be confused with iOS UIButton

Comment: Yes I was taking about UIButton, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

If your button is just not giving the animation, it might be an Xcode bug. I had a similar problem before, and I filed a bug, and it got fixed on the next Xcode version. Check out my SO question. [Toolbar bar button item not working properly in SplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684882/toolbar-bar-button-item-not-working-properly-in-splitviewcontroller)

If you really need to give it an animation, you could probably do it in code with something like this. Please note that this is untested so it may not work, or you might need some fixing, but you get the idea :)

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

self.button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

// Action

self.button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];

// Or with delay
[self performSelector:@selector(changeButtonColor) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Comment: I'm using 6.3. But is smells like another XCODE bug :-(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The button opened a transient popover. In order to close this popover due to an action I had coded

```
view.window!.orderOut(self)
```

After replacing it by

```
view.window!.performClose(self)
```

the strange effect was gone. I'm not sure, but this looks like a bug in the Swift runtime. I'll report it and see what comes out.